# Eclipse RCP TableViewer component not showing TAB character?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to display some content in Cell of TableViewer component. It displays almost every character except tab (\t) character. It looks like it ignores \t character. Any one know any fix for this?

For workaround to this issue, I tried replacing \t with few space characters and it looks like behavior of Tab character. But I wan't to know why '\t' is not properly displayed in TableViewer.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Textlayout and set the size of the tabs in pixelsusing setTabs().Here is an example:

```
package de.abas.erp.wb.base.tools.identifiersearchview;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class TabSnippet {

public static void main(final String [] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Table:\t\t Change style \t multiple times in cell");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    }
    final TextLayout textLayout = new TextLayout(display);
        textLayout.setText("SWT:\t Standard \t Widget \t Toolkit");
        textLayout.setTabs(new int[] { 100 });

        /*
         * NOTE: MeasureItem, PaintItem and EraseItem are called repeatedly.
         * Therefore, it is critical for performance that these methods be as
         * efficient as possible.
         */
        table.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
                textLayout.draw(event.gc, event.x, event.y);
            }
        });
        final Rectangle textLayoutBounds = textLayout.getBounds();
        table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(final Event e) {
                e.width = textLayoutBounds.width + 2;
                e.height = textLayoutBounds.height + 2;
            }
        });
    shell.setSize(400, 200);
    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    textLayout.dispose();
    display.dispose();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the \t character is rendered 0 width in SWT components, which is why you aren't seeing it. What do you want to use the tabs for? Typically a tab is used to align text to predefined column start points - could you maybe use separate table columns instead of tabs to achieve the same result? Or if you need to indent certain elements in a hierarchy, are you wanting to use a TreeViewer with [multiple columns](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTreeWithMulticolumns.htm).

For displaying the contents of a file, a [StyledText](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FStyledText.html) component would probably be more appropriate to your needs. This is the control used by Eclipse editors and the like, and is very flexible.

It supports tabs and you could use a [LineStyleListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FLineStyleListener.html) to render table like row borders. There are a couple of excellent tutorials to get you started:

[Getting Your Feet Wet with the SWT StyledText Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/StyledText%201/article1.html)

[Into the Deep End of the SWT StyledText Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/StyledText%202/article2.html)

If you are not wanting editing support your usage will be much simpler than much of what is described in those tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am displaying the content of the File inside TableViewer, each row of the Table is representing a line of the file. Is there a way to override the rendering behavior for \t character, Any idea?